# Variable not being passed to second select dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have two dropdowns, one displays States from HTML SELECT, and the next one populates from MYSQL query of markets matched to the state selected. After selection of the Market, the SID should appear. The problem is the code remembering the $pickstate var when you select the $market var so Mysql query can display the SID result.

```
<?php
// Get State from above form.
    $pickstate = $_POST['state'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Market FROM ppc WHERE State='" . $pickstate . "'");

// After State is selected from MySQL, populate Market Dropdown.
echo '<form style="display:inline-block;" action="" method="POST"><select id="Market" name="Market" onchange="this.form.submit();">';
echo '<option value="">Select Your Market</option>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo ( '<option value= "' .$row['Market']. '">'.$row['Market'].'</option>' );
}
echo "</select></form><br />";

// Get SID Result
$market = $_POST['Market'];
$sid = mysql_query("SELECT SID FROM ppc WHERE State='" . $pickstate . "' AND Market='" . $market . "'");

// This is for debugging only.    
// This shows, until market is selected.. then vanishes.
echo $pickstate . "<br />"; 
// This shows after market has been chosen. 
echo $market . "<br />"; 


// "SHOULD" Display SID.
if ($state != null && $market != null) {
echo '<p style="display:inline-block;margin:0;padding:0;">&nbsp;&nbsp; Use: ';
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sid)) {
    echo $row['SID'] . '  ';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql`, use `mysqli` or `PDO`. Carry on...

Answer (score 0):

it will not work like that .

the query is server side . you may consider to send your selected value to another page and then get values from your query

OR you can use ajax .

Comment: Any ideas as to where to find any documentation on your suggestion? As you may be able to tell via my code, I am no coder. I am learning this all as it was dumped onto me. Thanks for any help.

Comment: just post to other page not to same page , and then get variables back to your page by many methods , (session , get , post ,....).

Comment: if you want ajax just do in google learn ajax step by step , i dont know good sites